# Python Math Game: List/Dictionaries

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to build a math game where a randomly generated math question corresponds to a right answer and a right quotes and/or fact. I'm working on building a list/dictionary. However, I cannot figure out how to  substitute the question from the dictionary into  the raw_input for math_answer.

```
import random
# imported a random module

random_math_questions = {'question':'1*1=','answer':1, 'quote' :'What you are, you are by accident of birth; what I am,I am by myself.\n There are and will be a thousand princes; there is only one Beethoven."'};
# read from a txt file later???

print random_math_questions['question']
math_answer = int(raw_input("What is the answer to random_math_questions[0]? "))

if math_answer == random_math_questions['answer']:
    print random_math_questions['quote']
else:
    print "Try again"
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the answer out with a friend. Below is what we came up with...

```
math_answer = int(raw_input("What is the answer to " + random_math_questions["question"] +"? : "))
```